# Umask for the SFTP users

Tags: 20.04, ssh, sftp, pam

My company has a syntax in /etc/pam.d/sshd file on our SFTP server:

```
session optional pam_umask.so umask=444
```

I found this command changes the permission of the uploaded file from 644 to 222 for all SFTP clients.
Is that possible to do match the user in this syntax?
I only want this command to be effective when a specific user uploads files and keeps 644 for the rest of the users.

I am very new to Ubuntu, any help is appreciated!

Comment: According to `man pam_umask`, the module will use a *"umask= entry in the user's GECOS field"* first - but I haven't tried it

Comment: @steeldriver  It works! You are right! I put the 'umask=0444'  between GID and the home directory. Thank you so much!  Could you please post the answer below? Then I can accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks - I have added a brief answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man pam_umask` (libpam-modules version 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1)<sup>1</sup>:

> ```
>    The PAM module tries to get the umask value from the following places
>    in the following order:
>
>    ·   umask= entry in the user's GECOS field
>
>    ·   umask= argument
>
>    ·   UMASK= entry from /etc/default/login
>
>    ·   UMASK entry from /etc/login.defs (influenced by USERGROUPS_ENAB in
>        /etc/login.defs)
> ```

So it should be possible to set a per-user umask for user `someuser` in the GECOS field, for example using

```
sudo chfn -o umask=0444 someuser
```

and then either setting `umask=0022` in the `pam_umask` entry in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file - or perhaps better, omit the `umask=` there altogether so that other users fall back to the umask specified in the default files.

---

Notes:

1. the order appears to be different in earlier versions, prioritizing the `umask=` argument in the configuration file above that in the GECOS entry.

Comment: Thank you so much!