# How to set default file permissions for files created via GUI?

Tags: 20.04, permissions

How do I set default file permissions for files created via the GUI--e.g., in Nautilus, LibreOffice, or any other desktop application?

The default 775 for directories and 664 for files is far too permissive for my taste. I don't use ACLs (or, at least, not to my knowledge).

I have tried setting umask in ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc, but these do not appear to have any effect.

Thanks.

Comment: It's done via `pam_umask` AFAIK, using values from /etc/login.defs - see related [Umask for the SFTP users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328704/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver That did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

```
sudo chfn -o umask=xxxx someuser
```

where xxxx is the four-digit umask and someuser is the user's name. This adds a field to /etc/passwd specifying the umask for the user in question.