# How to set umask for the user in linux permanently

Tags: 20.04, umask

Any other alternative where to set umask in linux permanently without modifying the bashrc/ profile files

Comment: Why would you wish an alternative? Please elaborate how you do it know and why you would want to do it different.

Comment: One alternative is to set it via the pam_umask module - see for example [Umask for the SFTP users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328704/178692)

Comment: "Permanently"? User has access to the `umask` `bash` subcommand.